# Why did my POST to AWS API Gateway failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, restful-authentication

I use POSTMAN to test my Cloudformation created APIs

```
POST https://6pppnxxxh.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/users
```

I got

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

My prod stage
[image]

I doublechecked PROD Invoke URL.
How to solve this problem?
I tried with curl

```
 curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{ "emailaddress" : "acj@rambler.ru,"first name" : "Aca","last name" : "Ljubascikic", "password" : "bbbac_96"}' https://6pppnxxxh.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/users
```

The same issue

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

How to test from CLI?

Comment: Could you confirm Auth setting for this route is None?

Comment: How to confirm Auth setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot `/Prod/users` is a `PUT` method and you are using `POST` in your command. I would confirm that first.

Hope this helps.